# Is there a way to do a partial checkin in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a file that has two independent modifications. I would only like to commit one of them.

Is there any way to only check in part of a file (without me modifying or shelving/unshelving it)?

Essentially, create a temp file on commit that then gets checked in instead of the file on disk?

Comment: that is an interesting question... since their source control is db based not file based it does seem like a possible feature. However, I can't think of a time where I really would have used it. For one thing, you wouldn't even be able to see if the code was buildable or complete doing something like that.

Comment: It's 2017 and I am still wishing TFS had a way to stage partial files, ala `git add -p`

Comment: Agreed; we now have Visual Studio 2017 and would have thought that checking in just specific files was possible.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No, the only way is to **shelve** what changes you have, revert back or the previous version and apply the changes that you want to commit.  After committing them, revert back to the shelved version.

Comment: Does this also apply if TFS uses git as backend?

Comment: @Marcel No, with git as backend you can perform partial commits without worries.